# How to apply floating label to select2 dropdown?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using select2 plugin for select dropdown. I have more than one select dropdown boxes in the page and I need to apply the floating label to the selected dropdown.

I have tried and googled but I could not find any desired results as I expected.

I have provided the code that I have tried so far.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
      <label class="hor-menu visible-xs visible-xs control-label col-sm-1"></label>
      <div class="form-group form-md-line-input form-md-floating-label" style="margin-top: 13px;">
        <select name="cboNGrp" id="cboNGrp" class="form-control select2me input-xlarge" data-live-search="true" data-size="8"></select>
        <label class="form_control_1 head_ctrl_label" style="padding-top: 2px;">Type</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group form-md-line-input head_ctrl">
        <label class="hor-menu visible-xs visible-xs control-label  col-sm-1"></label>
        <select name="cboEmrGrp" id="cboEmrGrp" class="select2me form-control input-xlarge"></select>
        <label class="form_control_1 head_ctrl_label">E / M</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.select2me').click(function(e){
    if($(this).find('select2-dropdown-open')) {
        $('label.head_ctrl_label').css('margin-top', '-25px'); 
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[Image showing user clicks the Dropdown to select Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V13Bl.png)

[Image showing the bug floating label applies to all the dropdown not only selected one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKrGG.png)

Comment: The above JS code is works but applies to all the select box in the page. I need to apply the code to the current select box where the user select.

Comment: create a fiddle with your code

Comment: use $(' select2-dropdown-open.head_ctrl_label ').css('margin-top', '-25px'); in js

Comment: No, $(' select2-dropdown-open.head_ctrl_label ').css('margin-top', '-25px');  not working.

Comment: @sravs, JS code works but applies -25 margin to all select dopdowns when Im trying to select one dropdown. Pls check the images I have attached.

Comment: no you need to change js code only...you are applying margin to all label with head_ctrl_label class..so all dropdowns are effecting..create one fiddle so that we can try your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this will help you!

```
$('select').select2().on('select2:open', (elm) => {
    const targetLabel = $(elm.target).prev('label');
    targetLabel.addClass('selected');
}).on('select2:close', (elm) => {
    const target = $(elm.target);
    const targetLabel = target.prev('label');
    const targetOptions = $(elm.target.selectedOptions);
    if (targetOptions.length === 0) {
        targetLabel.removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

SCSS

```
label {
    &.selected {
        top: 0;
        font-size: 11px;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #dfdfdf;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 15px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

[Code pen explanation](https://codepen.io/Mustafar/full/bZdYBE)

Comment: Please explain your answere.

Comment: @MrMaavin, see link above.

Comment: The Code Pen link? @MartinScheer this is not an explanaition. It only provides a full example. It is also good to have a full example, But maybe you could **explain what you did** to solve the problem **and why**.

Comment: @MrMaavin, the answer provided by 'sravs' is already accepted.
I hope 'MrMaavin' code applies the `selected` class to the `label` when `select2` open and close.

Answer (score 3):

You must first install Select2 bootstrap 5 theme (https://apalfrey.github.io/select2-bootstrap-5-theme/getting-started/download-install/):

npm install select2-bootstrap-5-theme

After just put this jquery script:

```js
$('.select2me').select2({
    theme: "bootstrap-5",
});
            
$('.select2me')
    .parent('div')
    .children('span')
    .children('span')
    .children('span')
    .css('height', ' calc(3.5rem + 2px)');
$('.select2me')
    .parent('div')
    .children('span')
    .children('span')
    .children('span')
    .children('span')
    .css('margin-top', '18px');
$('.select2me')
    .parent('div')
    .find('label')
    .css('z-index', '1');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2-bootstrap-5-theme@1.3.0/dist/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.min.css" />
<!-- Or for RTL support -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2-bootstrap-5-theme@1.3.0/dist/select2-bootstrap-5-theme.rtl.min.css" />

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-floating">
  <select class="form-select select2me" id="floatingSelect"  aria-label="Floating label select example">
    <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
  <label for="floatingSelect">Works with selects</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
$('.select2me').click(function(e){
   if($(this).find('select2-dropdown-open')) {
      $(this).next('.head_ctrl_label').css('margin-top', '-25px'); }
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

only css solution

```
    <style>
    .select2-container--bootstrap-5 .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered{
        float: right;
    }
    .control-label{
        z-index:11;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Please provide more detail and context for this answer. Why is this better than the already-accepted answer?